# password_verify stops working after changing hash

Tags: php

I'm working on implementing the ability for users to edit their passwords.

I'm using PASSWORD_BYCRYPT, and password_verify works fine after creating a user, but as soon as a user edits their password, it stops working.

Password change:

```
else if (isset($_POST["submitUpdateSettingsPW"])) {
    $passwordText = $_POST["passwordChangeInput"];
    $userID = $_SESSION["userID"];
    $passwordNew = password_hash($passwordText, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET password = '$passwordNew' WHERE id = '$userID';";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
      header("location: settings.php");
    }
    else {
      header("location: settings.php?message=Something+went+wrong.+You+may+not+have+the+permissions+to+do+this.");
    }
}
```

Password creation

```
else if (isset($_POST["submitSignup"])) {
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["emailInput"]);
$passwordText = $_POST["passwordInput"];
$password = password_hash($passwordText, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$signupSQLCheck = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $signupSQLCheck);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    $signupSQL = "INSERT INTO users set email = '$email', password = '$password'";
    mysqli_query($conn, $signupSQL);
    header("location: login.php?message=Your+account+is+active.+You+may+now+login.");
}

else {
    header("location: login.php?message=This+email+is+already+registered.+Do+you+want+to+<a href = 'login.php'>login</a>?");
}
```

}

Password verify (works fine until changing password)

```
if (isset($_POST["submitLogin"])) {
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["emailInput"]);
$passwordText = $_POST["passwordInput"];
$loginSQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $loginSQL);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$hash = $row["password"];

if (password_verify($passwordText, $hash)) {
  $_SESSION["user"] = 1;
    $_SESSION["userID"] = $row["id"];
    header("location: index.php");
}
}

else {
    header("location: login.php?message=Incorrect+email+or+password.+Do+you+want+to+<a href = 'signup.php'>sign up</a>?");
}
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not your problem, but `$passwordText = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["passwordChangeInput"]);`.... on't do this, besides being unnecessary, it's actually modifying the user's password

Comment: Have you confirmed that the password entry in the database actually changes when you run password change?  Do you have any error logs anywere?

Comment: Dont escape string the password.

Comment: @nic3500 The password entry does change. Actually, the whole password_verify() function not only fails but acts as a syntax error - blank white page - only after changing the password.

Comment: Okay, I removed the escaping from my code. Thanks

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: passwordInput in /var/www/html/johndo-git/logsign.php on line 8 was the error. After a bit more investigative work, I fixed it: the form was called "pwordInput" instead of "passwordInput". No idea why it still worked before changing the password, but I'll take it. Thanks all.